# Get the indices of the last element of each run in vector

Tags: r

How to the get the index of last element of each run?

For example:
Let us consider a vector

```
x=c(1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7,8,9,9,9,9)
```

Want get the output vector

```
x1=1 2 3 6 7 9 10 11 15
```

Tried using:

```
rank(x)
```

It is not giving the desired result.

Comment: You can use `cumsum(rle(x)$lengths)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Post?

Comment: Another option is `tapply(seq_along(x), x, FUN= tail, 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Probably a dupe, but here you go..)

You can use the magic powers of `?rle` combined with `cumsum`:

```
cumsum(rle(x)$lengths)
#[1]  1  2  3  6  7  9 10 11 15
```

The output of `rle` is:

```
rle(x)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:9] 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 4
#  values : num [1:9] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the which() function in R

```
    k<-as.vector(unique(x))
    x1<-vector()
    for(i in 1:length(k)){
        x1[i]=tail(which(x==k[i]),1)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.